# « Rire dans sa barbe » : sujet au féminin possible ?

Tags: expressions, usage

On sait qu'il n'est nullement nécessaire qu'un homme ait le moindre poil au menton pour qu'on puisse dire de lui qu'il [rit dans sa barbe](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/rire-dans-sa-barbe) (expression familière). Donc, apparemment, l'expression pourrait être employée pour les imberbes, les garçons adolescents et, pourquoi pas, les femmes. En fait, ce pourrait ne  pas  être le cas pour les personnes du sexe féminin ; un ngram montre que l'expression est utilisée avec le pronom « il » mais pas le pronom « elle » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+rit+dans+sa+barbe%2Celle+rit+dans+sa+barbe&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20rit%20dans%20sa%20barbe%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cil%20rit%20dans%20sa%20barbe%3B%2Cc0)).

Les sources que je peux accéder ne précisent rien à propos de l'usage.

[expressio](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/rire-dans-sa-barbe), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rire_dans_sa_barbe), [expressions françaises](https://www.expressions-francaises.fr/19-r/1719-rire-dans-sa-barbe.html), [leparisien](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/rire%20dans%20sa%20barbe/fr-fr/), [Académie](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9R2696), [cordial](https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/rire.php)

Je n'ai moi-même aucun souvenir d'un emploi quelconque avec un sujet féminin, sauf l'exemple d'une femme qui utilise une expression très similaire (mais de sens différent) dans une  [interview de Charles Palant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQb1e2Bvv-A%5Ct=2h8m40s).

*Question*

- L'emploi de cette expression avec un sujet féminin peut-il être confirmé ?
- Est-ce qu'un principe quelconque empêche l'usage de l'expression avec un sujet féminin ?
- Y a-t-il une expression équivalente qui serait utilisable en général sans avoir à se soucier d'une quelconque incongruité ?

Comment: [Baba la turque](https://www.classicfm.com/discover-music/latest/maleficent-wicked-women/baba-the-turk-stravinsky-rakes-progress/) se rit dans sa barbe depuis 60 ans ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On peut tout à fait utiliser « rire dans sa barbe » en parlant d'une femme. « Elle rit dans sa barbe » est moins courant que « il rit dans sa barbe », mais je ne sais pas dans quelle mesure c'est parce que l'expression semble moins naturelle, parce que le « il » est aussi un pronom neutre par défaut, et dans quelle mesure c'est parce qu'il y a moins de littérature qui parle de femmes.

Google Ngrams ne conserve pas les n-grams très rares dans sa base de données, donc il ne permet pas de distinguer entre une suite de mots rare et une suite de mot vraiment inusitée. Même pour les n-grams qui qui sont juste au-dessus du seuil, les données sont peu exploitables : un seul ouvrage dont plusieurs éditions sont indexées peut créer un pic significatif.

En cherchant sur Google Books, on trouve des [« elle rit dans sa barbe »](https://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&q=%22elle+rit+dans+sa+barbe%22), mais en moins grand nombre que [« il rit dans sa barbe »](https://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&q=%22il+rit+dans+sa+barbe%22). [Au 19e siècle](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elle+rit+dans+sa+barbe%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899), par exemple, il n'y a que deux textes (*L'Enfant* de Jules Vallès et un texte signé Jules Lecomte dans *Le Monde illustré — plus un faux positif puisque [le sujet y est « une personne »](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Almanach_des_%C3%A9tudians_belges_des_provin/2MZPAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22elle+rit+dans+sa+barbe%22&pg=PA143&printsec=frontcover), qui pose justement la question de si cette expression a un sens en parlant d'un homme rasé, mais il s'agit d'un texte satirique).

Je pense que la plupart des femmes francophones se *battent les couilles* que le sujet soit masculin ou féminin lorsqu'elles emploient cette expression.

Comment: Elles sont déjà _toutes_ aussi vulgaires ?

Comment: @LPH … *la plupart* est loin de signifier *toutes…* la francophonie n'est pas réservée à l'ancienne noblesse et la bourgeoisie. Il faut être seulement dans leur cercle d'ami·es pour ouïr des propos semblables qui vous écorcheraient les oreilles, sans vulgarité, en utilisant des mots de la francophonie vivante, orale, complice… une forme d'expression poétique qui transmet la bonne humeur…

Comment: @Personne Plus besoin d'être une femme pour se battre les steaks des pères-la-pudeur :-)

Answer (score 2):

Il peut être utile de rappeler qu'il s'agit d'un emploi *au [figuré](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sens_propre_et_sens_figur%C3%A9)* ou par analogie/métaphore (voir [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/barbe), [Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9B0382) à *barbe*) comme *parler dans sa barbe* (« de manière peu audible ») et non du sens au propre et c'est ce qui explique, il me semble, qu'on ne réfère pas à la barbe de la personne dont on parle quand on emploie l'expression, et qu'autrement on trouve des exemples d'autres expressions de cette catégorie avec des abstractions (*...à la barbe de la censure, des affamés*, au TLFi). On tend vers l'[*idiotisme*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiotisme) corporel sans nécessairement le retrouver et dans certains cas on peut aussi imaginer un scénario où la locution a aussi son sens au propre et c'est le contexte qui nous l'indiquerait.

Par ailleurs on peut observer (et ce n'est absolument pas déterminant) que dans ces expressions la *barbe* est un prototype pour ce qui cache ou interfère avec l'action ou la perception que l'on en a, par opposition à d'autres emplois, toujours au figuré, où c'est employé pour marquer la virilité et où la question de l'adéquation des caractéristiques se poserait encore plus directement au propre, comme par exemple « avoir de la barbe au menton » qu'on a indirectement évoqué en question. Reste que dans ce dernier cas, encore une fois, même si le [sens](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/barbe/7933#160459) était « appartenir au sexe masculin », ce n'est pas la présence ou l'absence de barbe chez la personne désignée qui rendrait l'emploi plus ou moins juste.

Comment: D'un point de vue fondamental, très juste.

Answer (score 1):

L'emploi de cette expression avec un sujet féminin peut-il être confirmé ?
=> Oui. On peut plus largement trouver des exemples attestés et anciens de toutes les erreurs possibles et imaginables en français.

Est-ce qu'un principe quelconque empêche l'usage de l'expression avec un sujet féminin ?
=> Oui. Le fait qu'une femme ne saurait avoir de barbe (hors cas pathologique)

Y a-t-il une expression équivalente qui serait utilisable en général sans avoir à se soucier d'une quelconque incongruité ?
=> Oui. Rire sous cape, par exemple.

Comment: 1/ En effet, cet usage chez les femmes semblerait bizarre, comme il le semblerait aussi plus ou moins  chez les hommes qui n'ont pas de barbe (c'est à dire ceux qui se la rasent). Est-ce à dire finalement que cette expression française n'a pas été une très bonne idée ? 2/ Très bon substitut, il me revient à l'esprit maintenant.

Comment: La censure va bon train, je vois...